How to stop Linux PC throwing away bluetooth phone audio
I have my PC (Dell Mobile Precision Workstation 7770 running openSUSE Leap 15.5) set up to connect to my phone (Samsung Galaxy S21 Ultra) by Bluetooth whenever it is in range, using a cron task periodically running https://github.com/jrouleau/bluetooth-autoconnect. This is so that I can easily do Bluetooth file transfers.
Unfortunately this causes phone audio notification sounds to be lost. The phone thinks that the PC is a connected audio output device and sends the sound to the PC, but I can't find a way to route the sound to the PC speakers. Neither PulseAudio Manager nor PulseAudio Preferences recognises Bluetooth as an audio source.
Using the Bluetooth settings on the phone to tell it not to connect to the PC as an audio device helps, but I think it will leave me having the same problem with the audio from phone calls. If I tell the phone not to connect with the PC for calls either, it won't connect at all.
A better solution would be either to make the PC refuse to act as a Bluetooth audio sink, or make it route the data to the speakers if it does act as an audio sink. However I can't find any way of doing this.
rparkins@rparkins77:~> wireplumber
C 06:50:52.502876               GLib (null):(null):(null): Failed to set scheduler settings: Operation not permitted
W 06:50:52.638543  spa.bluez5.native ../spa/plugins/bluez5/backend-native.c:1747:sco_listen: listen(): Address already in use
W 06:50:52.641166  spa.bluez5.native ../spa/plugins/bluez5/backend-native.c:2304:register_profile_reply: RegisterProfile() failed: org.bluez.Error.NotPermitted
W 06:50:52.641194  spa.bluez5.native ../spa/plugins/bluez5/backend-native.c:2304:register_profile_reply: RegisterProfile() failed: org.bluez.Error.NotPermitted
W 06:50:52.645770 m-portal-permissio ../modules/module-portal-permissionstore.c:63:wp_portal_permissionstore_plugin_lookup: <WpPortalPermissionStorePlugin:0xe3f0e0> Failed to call Lookup: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.portal.Error.NotFound: No entry for camera
W 06:50:52.646907 m-portal-permissio ../modules/module-portal-permissionstore.c:63:wp_portal_permissionstore_plugin_lookup: <WpPortalPermissionStorePlugin:0xe3f0e0> Failed to call Lookup: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.portal.Error.NotFound: No entry for camera
W 06:50:52.647761 m-portal-permissio ../modules/module-portal-permissionstore.c:63:wp_portal_permissionstore_plugin_lookup: <WpPortalPermissionStorePlugin:0xe3f0e0> Failed to call Lookup: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.portal.Error.NotFound: No entry for camera
W 06:50:52.657915 m-portal-permissio ../modules/module-portal-permissionstore.c:63:wp_portal_permissionstore_plugin_lookup: <WpPortalPermissionStorePlugin:0xe3f0e0> Failed to call Lookup: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.portal.Error.NotFound: No entry for camera
W 06:50:52.658652 m-portal-permissio ../modules/module-portal-permissionstore.c:63:wp_portal_permissionstore_plugin_lookup: <WpPortalPermissionStorePlugin:0xe3f0e0> Failed to call Lookup: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.portal.Error.NotFound: No entry for camera
W 06:50:52.659551 m-portal-permissio ../modules/module-portal-permissionstore.c:63:wp_portal_permissionstore_plugin_lookup: <WpPortalPermissionStorePlugin:0xe3f0e0> Failed to call Lookup: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.portal.Error.NotFound: No entry for camera


After that, wireplumber gets stuck, won't respond to commands from terminal or ^C or ^D. I had to kill it from another terminal window.
In any case, running a command doesn't help me, because I would have to run it every time the phone reconnects when it comes into range of my PC. That would defeat the whole point of making the phone reconnect automatically so that I don't have to remember to reconnect it if it has been out of range, before trying to send a file by bluetooth.
Changing the configuration file for the pipewire daemon so that it connects the Bluetooth audio source whenever it becomes available might help, but the documentation doesn't give any indication about how to do that.

Check out WirePlumber.

@JayCravens See my edits to the question, too long to fit in a comment.

Here is a wealth of info related to this.  This is for BSD, but it all still applies.  You also need PipeWire configured for that WirePlumber setup.  This is going to take some advanced configuration.  I'll see if I can find anything else to explore. JACK to pulse bridge is something to look at and blues-alsa as well.

The BSD stuff is about connecting a Bluetooth sink to the PC. I want to do the opposite - connect a Bluetooth source. In fact it does appear to be connected - at least the phone thinks that it is. My problem is that the PC doesn't do anything with the audio stream that the phone sends to it. PulseAudio manager doesn't show the phone as a source, although the system tray Bluetooth widget says that it is connected.

It really sounds like blues-alsa is what you need.

My original problem was that if I took my phone out of Bluetooth range from my PC for a while, and then brought it back into range, Bluetooth file transfers would fail. It turns out that if I regularly try to reconnect from my PC, but I tell the phone not to connect as a media player or using the handsfree protocol, it doesn't connect as I reported above. However Bluetooth file transfers now work. This is because of the layering in the Bluetooth stack. The full explanation is off-topic for my original question, and possibly off-topic for this part of stackexchange. Ask me if you want to know.

I would still like to know how to route sound from my phone to the speakers on my PC, but it's no longer an immediate problem.
